# Get HTML source from URL

Tags: android, html, url, get

I have this URL, http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD%3D%3FINR

which returns the current USD->INR conversion rate as text.

the text displayed on the screen is the only text in the HTML source of the page.

I was struggling to get that HTML source as many things I tried returned Exceptions.

for e.g.:

```
public static String getHtml(String url)
throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));

    result = reader.readLine();
    return result;
}
```

returned an exception when called from

```
try {
String test = getHtml("google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD%3D%3FINR");
    Log.d("ASDADS", test);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ASDASD", "FAILED");
    }
```

Also, I have added the INTERNET permission in Manifest, and my network is also working without fault.

Comment: the url you provided doesnt return html it returns json so you cant display html

Answer (score 0):

Make your URL something like,

```
"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD%3D%3FINR"
```

Also the result from it is in **JSON** not in **HTML**.. So parse the result like JSON..

Comment: ok thanks a lot! but i still can't figure out how to get the JSON to work by using DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost, etc.

can you PLEASE post/link to a function that accepts a URL, and returns a string value which is obtained from the JSON.

i'm asking you because i've tried too many things and everything keeps going to the catch block. n i don't know what's going wrong! thanks in advance